# Do not show AM/PM in textbox ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have a field where I ask the user how much time a task has taken so I do not want to see AM or PM in my textfield how can I remove it form my textbox.

Here is my code.

```
         <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
  <label for="validationCostComponente">Tiempo cotizado</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1"   TextMode="time"  runat="server" class="form-control" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" ></asp:TextBox>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Please choose a username.
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it here is my solution.

```
.form-control::-webkit-datetime-edit-ampm-field {
    display: none;
}

input[type=time]::-webkit-clear-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: -10px;
}
```